# Display Bootstrap ModalPopup on Click on ASP Button without using Modalpopupextender

Tags: javascript, c#, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to call a javascript function on Click event of ASP Button and from that function I am trying to click the html button that will invoke the Modal Pop.

Status: I am able to file the html button's click event and run an alertbox in it but not ModalPopup. I am also able to open the ModalPopup by directly clicking the HTML Code.

Code:
//Code

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)btn.Parent;
    Label id = (Label)ri.FindControl("payid");
    Add_Account_Head_1.headid_property = id.Text;

    update1.Update();

    string script = "showpop();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                          "ServerControlScript", script, true);

}
```

In Body Section

```
 $("#btn1").click(function () {
         //     alert('This has been clicked');
        $("#myModal").modal('show');


    });
```

In the Head Section

```
     function showpop() {

            var button = document.getElementById('btn1');
            button.click();
        };
```

Comment: provide some html of modal

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to invoke the `modal.show` directly from the server side. But make sure that `#myModal` is the correct selector. You can verify the ID from the dev tools.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;
    RepeaterItem ri = (RepeaterItem)btn.Parent;
    Label id = (Label)ri.FindControl("payid");
    Add_Account_Head_1.headid_property = id.Text;

    update1.Update();

    string script = "showpop();";
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                          "ServerControlScript", "$('#myModal').modal('show');", true);

}
```

Comment: *The page just refreshes* - Isn't the modal inside an update panel? Also did you verify the ID of the modal div?

Comment: Modal is not inside any update panel..... An Update Panel is although inside the Modal Body

Comment: That explains why the modal is not opening up. You should add the modal div inside the update panel. Also when you do that its ID on browser will no longer be `myModal`, it will become something like `UpdatePanel1_myModal`. So check that from the dev tools and update your code.

Comment: Checked nothing happens..... ID's of static Html divs doesn't change in any update panel...

Comment: Did you check that the update panel is getting updated? Maybe mark the updatemode as always. Or, can you post the markup of that entire update panel in the question?